# Vertical Slide content area in Android

Tags: android

I am implementing the following screen.

[image: denko about page]

If what I have done so far is useful in helping me, the following is the code. It's a `Fragment`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/station_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_bar_strip">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/title_bar_gas_pump"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/denko_about"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/denko_title_bar_text_colour"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_denko_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/denko_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/about_content_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/station_title_strip"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_denko_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/denko_about_grey"></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am having difficulty producing the content area. As you can see swiping up or down should allow the user to view different content pages and the transition should have a slide-up and slide-down animations. In addition to controlling the page selection with swipe gestures, the user should also be able to flip through pages by pressing the green circles on the right.

Can anyone direct me to the right path to do that?